# Statistics Parameter Estimators

Tags: statistics

I've been struggling to figure out how to do the following question:

[question http://puu.sh/5AIRS.png](http://puu.sh/5AIRS.png)

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the questions? If yes, what is it exactly about this problem that gives you trouble?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not quite sure how to calculate E() of theta to check for bias...

Answer (score 0):

For part (a), the key is to use the fact that

$E(\bar{X}_{n}^{2}) = E(\bar{X}_{n})^{2} + \textrm{var}(X_{n}) = \mu^{2} + \sigma^{2}/n$

It then follows that

$E(\hat{\theta}) = E(\bar{X}_{n}^{2}) - 4E(X_{n}) + 4
=  \mu^{2} + \sigma^{2}/n - 4\mu + 4
= (\mu - 2)^{2} + \sigma^{2}/n$.

Hence,

$E(\hat{\theta}) - \theta = \sigma^{2}/n$.